# Mechanize (Python) - Trouble with form submission

Tags: python, web-scraping, mechanize

I'm trying to do something very simple using Python's Mechanize library. I want to go to: JobSearch">http://careers.force.com/jobs/ts2_JobSearch, select Dublin Ireland from the drop down list, and then hit enter.

I've written a very short Python script for this, but for some reason when I run it, it returns the HTML for the default search page rather than the search page that is produced after selecting the location (Dublin Ireland) and hitting enter. I have no idea what is going wrong:

```
import mechanize

link = "http://careers.force.com/jobs/ts2__JobSearch"

br = mechanize.Browser()
br.open(link)
br.select_form('j_id0:j_id1:atsForm' )
br.form['j_id0:j_id1:atsForm:j_id38:1:searchCtrl'] =  ["Ireland - Dublin"]

response = br.submit()

newsite = response.read()
```

Answer (score 0):

This is in case you're still having this problem or if not, in case anyone else is having this problem in the future....

I looked at the postdata that was being sent by your browser when you manually selected something and wrote a function for you that will get you to the page you want by manually performing a POST operation with urllib.urlencoded data.  Cheers.

```
import mechanize,cookielib,urllib

def get_search(html,controls):
    #viewstate
    s=re.search('ViewState" value="', html).span()[1]
    e=re.search('"',html[s:]).span()[0]+s
    state=html[s:e]
    #viewstateversion
    s=re.search('ViewStateVersion', html).span()[1]
    s=s+re.search('value="', html[s:]).span()[1]
    e=re.search('"', html[s:]).span()[0]+s
    version=html[s:e]
    #viewstatemac
    s=re.search('ViewStateMAC',html).span()[1]
    s=s+re.search('value=\"',html[s:]).span()[1]
    e=re.search('"',html[s:]).span()[0]+s
    mac=html[s:e]
    return {controls[0]:controls[0], controls[1]:'',controls[2]:'Ireland - Dublin', controls[3]:'Search','com.salesforce.visualforce.ViewState':state,'com.salesforce.visualforce.ViewStateVersion':version,'com.salesforce.visualforce.ViewStateMAC':mac}

#Define variables and create a mechanize browser
link = "http://careers.force.com/jobs/ts2__JobSearch"
br = mechanize.Browser()
cj=cookielib.LWPCookieJar()
br.set_cookiejar(cj)
br.open(link)

#get the html data
html=br.response().read()

#get the control names from the correct form
br.select_form(nr=1)
controls=[control.name for control in br.form.controls]

#run function with html and control names list as parameters and run urllib.urlencode on what gets returned
postdata=urllib.urlencode(get_search(br.response().read(), controls))

#go to the webpage again but this time also submit the encoded data
br.open(link, postdata)

#There Ya Go
print br.response().read()
```